# fill single td with 3 colors in different percentage

Tags: asp.net

I have a Asp Table.
Is to possible to fill the single tablecell with 3 backcolors.
I want to fill the tablecell with 30% of red color,40% yellow and 30% of white colr.
Can Fill the single cell in a row like that? then cloud you say how to do that

Comment: If td width is 100% i want to fill that td with 40% red color,30%yellow and remain 30 white like that....

Answer (score 1):

```
<table style="width:200px">
    <tr>
        <td style="width:100%">
            <div style="width:30%; background-color:red; float:left;">red</div>
            <div style="width:40%; background-color:yellow; float:left;">yellow</div>
            <div style="width:30%">white</div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution will work when you overflow the table cell also

[jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/QLkJ7/1/)

**HTML**

```
<table style="border: solid 1px black;">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="container">
                text for the table cell

                <div id="Color1" runat="server"></div>
                <div id="Color2" runat="server"></div>
                <div id="Color3" runat="server"></div>               
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Code Behind**

```
    Color1.Attributes.CssStyle("background-color") = "red";
    Color1.Attributes.CssStyle("width") = "30%";

    Color2.Attributes.CssStyle("background-color") = "yellow";
    Color2.Attributes.CssStyle("width") = "40%";
    Color2.Attributes.CssStyle("left") = "30%"; // Color1 width

    Color3.Attributes.CssStyle("background-color") = "white";
    Color3.Attributes.CssStyle("width") = "30%";
    Color3.Attributes.CssStyle("left") = "70%"; // Color1+Color2 width
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
    position: relative;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

#Color1 {
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    height: 100%;
    z-index:-1
}

#Color2 {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    height: 100%;
    z-index:-1
}

#Color3 {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    height: 100%;
    z-index:-1
}
```

Comment: HI thanks. But I want to set the color width every time from codebehind in asp.net. How can I do it?

Answer (score -1):

Your best bet is to set the td style to an image with 3 colors

```
td {
    background-image: url('3color.gif');
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

Comment: How you want to do that with a TD which is 100%? That mean that this TD's width can change on different browsers, screens or resolutions.

Comment: Test it out and see for yourself.  Also, the request is to set the background to a specific color, this way the user can still add content to the TD cell without having to create an element with absolute positioning.  edit: for future references, make sure you only down vote things that you understand.

Comment: Where are you seeing the request for adding content to the TD? @user823017 Do you need content in your TD?